# Телеграм бот на python не отправляет фото больше 1ого раза. В первый раз идет текст и фото, а в последующий только текст

Tags: python, telebot

```
@anime.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Eщеее':
        m = 0
        while m<= 5:
            anime.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo[m], reply_markup= knopkastart)
            m+=1
    else:
    
        anime.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не понимаю')
        anime.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('photo_2021-05-07_15-28-11.jpg', 'rb') )
    


anime.polling(none_stop= True)
```

[image: Вот]

Comment: Надо смотреть, что за результат возвращает функция `send_photo`, там скорее всего что-то вроде `{"ok": false, ...}`. Добавьте, пожалуйста, дополнительную информацию в вопрос.

Comment: Могу предположить, что проблема в не закрытом потоке, который возникает при передаче его в параметры - "open('photo_2021-05-07_15-28-11.jpg', 'rb')". Стоит попробовать закрыть. Но, как написали выше, вы предоставили довольно мало информации.

Comment: У меня возникла такая же проблема. Вам удалось устранить её?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего у вас просто не успевает телеграм принимать запросы
Так как на каждый запрос нужно время на обработку
Попробуйте прибавить туда `time.sleep(2)` после добавления к м.
Если же не получиться ещё раз то увеличьте с 2 до 3 и тд `time.sleep(3)`
Эта команда ждёт столько секунд сколько вы укажете скобках `time.sleep(кол-во секунд)`
Но не забудьте импортировать необхидимий модуль в начале `import time`